# Linear Combination of Vectors in 3 dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do you verify that linear combination of 2 independent vectors in 3D space generates a plane?

Comment: What is your definition of plane? A (maybe translated) 2D subspace of $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: @martín-blas-pérez-pinilla : yes

Comment: Dimension of the span of two independent vectors?

Comment: sorry i could not understand your comment

Comment: That with your definition of plane is trivially true. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span.

Comment: He means that by the parrallelogram law, if you add together all the possible linear combinations of 2 independent vectors you will get a plane of points. There are several definitions of a plane and one is that it is simply the linear combinations of 2 independent vectors so that there is nothing to varify in that sense.

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for the reply.I am just finding it hard to visualise in my head that indeed all the possible linear combinations of 2 independent vectors in 3D space will result in a plane of points. Can you suggest some image or graphic that could help with this.

Comment: Google 3D plotters - there should be plenty of online ones. The latest version of GeoGebra 3D (free and very easy to use) will let you easily visualize planes and other 3d objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy that $3x+y-2z = 0$ defines a plane through the origin then we can represent $(x, y, z)$ on the plane as a linear combination of 2 vectors. Put $y = -3x+2z$ then $$(x, y, z) = (x, -3x+2z, z) = (x, -3x, 0) + (0, 2z, z) = x(1, -3, 0) + z(0, 2, 1)$$
A linear combination of 2 vectors.
Conversely, if $x(1, -3, 0) + y(0, 2, 1)$ is a linear combination of 2 vectors  then $x(1, -3, 0) + z(0, 2, 1) = (x, -3x+2z, z)$ so that the y component of this combination is of the form $y = -3x+2z$ and you get the form $3x+y-2z = 0$ back

Comment: Thank you for explaining it with an example :)

Answer (score 0):

For a plane to be generated you must have at least two perpendicular vectors, hence independent from each other.

EDIT:

You can calculate the cross product of the two vectors to verify if they are linear independent from each other:

$$ \vec{W} = \vec{V}\times \vec{U} = \begin{vmatrix}
\vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k} \\ 
V_{\vec{i}} & V_{\vec{j}} & V_{\vec{k}} \\ 
U_{\vec{i}} & U_{\vec{j}} & U_{\vec{k}} 
\end{vmatrix} = \vec{i}(V_{\vec{j}} \: U_{\vec{k}} - V_{\vec{k}} \: U_{\vec{j}}) + \vec{j}(V_{\vec{i}} \: U_{\vec{k}} - V_{\vec{k}} \: U_{\vec{i}}) + \vec{k}(V_{\vec{i}} \: U_{\vec{j}} - V_{\vec{j}} \: U_{\vec{i}}) $$

If the vector resultant from the cross product, W, is (0;0;0), then U and V are a linear combination from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Pass any plane through the origin of an $x-y-z$ Cartesian coordinate system. Denote the plane by $K$. Let $A$ and $B$ be any two non-collinear vectors lying in plane $K$. Then any linear combination of vectors $A$ and $B$ is a vector lying in plane $K$ (i.e. if $c_1$ and $c_2$ are any two numbers, the vector $X = c_1 A + c_2 B$ lies in plane $K$). Moreover, any vector lying in plane $K$ can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors $A$ and $B$ (i.e. for any vector $X$ in plane $K$ there exist numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $X = c_1 A + c_2 B$ ). Note the closure concept involved. It is a closed system. The totality of all vectors in plane $K$ constitute a vector space. Vectors $A$ and $B$ constitute a basis for the space –- as would any other set of two non-collinear vectors lying in $K$. The dimension of the space is “two” (it is a two dimensional space). This space constitutes a two-dimensional subspace of the three dimensional space of the last paragraph. In fact, any plane passing through the origin of the $x-y-z$ coordinate system constitutes a two-dimensional subspace of three-dimensional space.

[Source](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c225.html)

Comment: how do you verify that the vectors generated by the linear combination c_1 A + c_2 B lies in the plane K?

Comment: I think you should take a look at this: http://www.solitaryroad.com/c225.html